# Finding the angular momentum of a rotation body w.r.t. a point on the body itself

Tags: angular-momentum

We have to find the angular momentum of a rolling disc about the point P on the disc but when we taking point how do we think of relative rotational and translational motion about that point on disc ...help me, please
[image]

Comment: Check out the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem). Try it out, and then if you have questions, post your work with a specific question that's not asking people to solve the entire problem.

Comment: Yeah use the parallel axis theorem as @tom10 suggested, then you're done.